# Boost converter - high current

Tags: voltage-regulator, boost, generator

Hi I have a generator with a 3 phase brushless motor acting as a generator rectified and smoothed to produce 0-12 volts however theoretically 2hp is approximately 1.5kw and at 12 volts before losses would give you a maximum current of 125 amps.

I have not load tested yet and voltage is dependent upon engine speed using pulleys to rotate it to get 12 volts at 10, 000 rpm, I wish to regulate this using a boost converter however I have not seen any for such high currents is there a reason for this.

I am assuming I cannot just build the standard boost circuit with high current components?

Comment: Specs input voltage: 0-12v input voltage 0-125 amp input current, output voltage of 12 volts.

Comment: Output current cannot  be boosted and must in fact reduce from conservation of energy as input current limit applies only to full voltage. Thus your spec must include load vs vs input current as a function of voltage or Pin max vs Pout vs RPM

Comment: Sorry my explanation wasn't clear I want a constant output voltage of 12 volts I'm not worried about increasing current.

Comment: There will be lower power out than in as a function of RPM and a Vin input minimum so 0V is not a good spec . Usually dynamic ratio of input has a limit and you need better specs

Comment: Well at Idle I get 6 volts minimum sorry if I'm not understanding it all correctly.

Comment: What load current max?  This is a poor way to generate 12V. You need a field control winding Alternator. like from a Car.

Comment: Load current max would be 150 amps and I'm using a brushless motor due to the increased efficiency over such alternators.

Comment: Are starting with a motor or a design goal? Where is the motor datasheet?

Comment: I don t see why you would need any power electronics here. If you have a generator you need a governor to regulate power and excitation control to regulate voltage...

Comment: MathieuL I don't think you read the post correctly as it was entirely asking how to regulate the power using a boost converter, what you describe applies to alternators and brushed generators that waste power when it is not desired or generates more than regulation setpoint this is what makes them less efficient than brushless generators and what you describes does not apply to brushless generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't see too many high current examples of a boost converter is that the magnetic component would become very large.  Remember that the peak current must be higher than the average (output) current, so the inductor that stores the energy from each pulse must have very heavy wire.  Similarly, the capacitor currents required to smooth the outputs will have very high currents and also must be large.  Finally, losses are large from every component (capacitor ESR, Inductor Resistance, and at 125 amps a diode drop is 100W or so). Small voltage drops are large efficiency liabilities when dealing with low supply voltages.

What you are suggesting is not impossible but would be challenging to say the least.

Comment: So how do companies like tesla overcome this in their electric vehicles using them up to 5kw or so

Comment: They chose components wisely - they are almost certainly not building 12v systems(!)